# Vaadin: how do I style a specific Grid?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a view with a Grid and I have a style for grid's cells:

```
[part~="cell"] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
    padding: var(--lumo-space-xl);
}
```

If I apply this style in via `@CssImport` like

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/example.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
```

it works but this will apply to all Vaadin Grids, that it not what I want.
If I don't specify `themeFor` this will not apply.

I want to apply this style just to the grid in the view where the grid is defined.

I tried using a theme like:

```
:host([theme~="custom-grid-theme"]) [part~="cell"] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
    padding: var(--lumo-space-xl);
}
```

and then on the grid

```
grid.addThemeName("custom-grid-theme");
```

but it doesn't work.

I tried too:

```
grid.getElement().setAttribute("theme", "custom-grid-theme");
```

this doesn't work too and it removes any GridVariant I applied.

I am using Vaadin 14.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS looks correct and `addThemeName()` seems to be used correctly too, so I would expect that to work.

You could try a couple of things:

1. Use the DOM inspector in the browser's devtools to check that the theme attribute is applied to the correct `vaadin-grid` element.
2. The entire solution could be simplified a bit since `vaadin-grid-cell-content` is not inside the grid's shadow DOM. Try this instead:

`grid.addClassName("custom-grid-theme");`

and in your global stylesheet (that is *not* imported with `themeFor`):

```
vaadin-grid.custom-grid-theme vaadin-grid-cell-content {
  padding: var(--lumo-space-xl);
}
```