# Vaadin: different behaviour with css while styling grid cell and combo box item

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am using V14, I have a simple test css file like:

```
.foobar {
  color: red;
}
```

on my test view class I import it with:

```
@CssImport(value="./styles/test.css")
```

and a `Grid` where I create a column like:

```
        grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<User>of(
                "<div class=\"foobar\">[[item.test]]</div>").
                withProperty("test", u -> u.getName())).
                setHeader("TEST");
```

and this works, the text in the column is red.

I have a `ComboBox` and I use to style item:

```
        comboBox.setRenderer(TemplateRenderer.<User>of(
                        "<div class=\"foobar\">[[item.test]]</div>").
                withProperty("test", u -> u.getName()));
```

and this doesn't work, the text is correct but it's not red.

If I use:

```
@CssImport(value="./styles/test.css", themeFor = "vaadin-combo-box-item")
```

It works for the combo box too.

Why this different behaviour?

Why in the grid I don't have to indicate the styled scope like `themeFor=vaadin-grid-cell-content` ? shadow root it's involved in the grid too.

Or am I styling the grid in wrong way?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in V14 the items in the ComboBox dropdown are inside the Shadow DOM, but the contents of Grid cells are not.

In V23 and V24 this has been changed so that ComboBox items are no longer in Shadow DOM.

Comment: But it's a bit confusing, the content of Grid cells are not but cells are?  I refer to a question asked time ago, there is an your answer too, in that case I had to use `themeFor` to access to shadow dom and apply css. Here the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/74761221/399637

Comment: Yup, the cells themselves are in shadow DOM, but the content wrappers in the cells are not. I can agree that these differences can be unexpected and confusing. Not sure why they were built like that. But like I said, this difference between CB and Grid have been removed in later versions. Also, V24 no longer requires shadow DOM styling for most things, making styling components a bit easier.